# Can colon (":") character be used in shapefile field names?

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes

I am trying to find out if the `:` character is allowed in the name of ESRI's shapefile field.

I googled, but I couldn't find an answer. Here is an interesting quote from the [article from ESRI FAQ](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000005588) stating:

> Eliminate any characters that are not alphanumeric character or an
>   underscore.

Does this mean that the `:` character is not allowed? Or is it allowed to use it, but it is recommended not to use it? If yes, then why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Field name restrictions inside a shapefile are determined by dBase limitations. There are four single rules:

1. Up to 10 character max.
2. First character in field name *must* start with a letter.
3. Field names are unique.
4. And, from [Understanding DBF Essentials](http://www.okstate.edu/sas/v7/sashtml/books/acespc/z0214453.htm)

> (...) they can contain any combination of the letters A through Z, the digits 0 through 9, the colon (:) (in dBASE II field names only), and the underscore (_).

ESRI Shapefile works with dBase III+.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @aldo_tapia !
I am actually exporting an .osm data to .shp file.
Converting colons in OSM key names to "_" in shp field names should be done through this line: ```attribute_name_laundering=yes``` in ```osmconf.ini``` file. However this seems to be some kind of bug. No matter if ```attribute_name_laundering``` is set to "yes", or "no" or even commented, the ":" from OSM key name is always converted to "_" in .shp field name.
Not sure why is this happening.

Comment: Which software are you using to convert `.osm` files?

Comment: GDAL ogr2ogr.exe. I tried on both GDAL 2.1.2 and GDAL 1.11.4, and got the same mentioned behavior.

Comment: Can you upload a part of your `.oms` file? I want to check what happens or if are an alternative way to export that kind of data

Comment: Here is an example file: ```https://www.dropbox.com/s/9d5sdwl3svhaba4/rome.osm?dl=0```. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: I tried in `R` using `osmar` and `rgdal` without problem, works perfect. I check field names in QGIS and are right. A [basic and simple code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/446o8hkfqwhuc1f/OSM_Shapefile.R?dl=0) . [And results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xg8cmqjvbg4jsc/rome_osm_test.zip?dl=0), check them.

Comment: Thank you @aldo_tapia!
I opened the r_polygons.shp, r_lines.shp and r_points.shp and they all contain very similar field names. These to be specific: ```id, visible, timestamp, version, changeset, user, uid, type, lat, lon```. But those field names do not contain the column character. So I do not understand what do you mean by: "I check field names in QGIS and are right"?

Comment: Because shapefiles have the same field than original file: `<node id="32633413" visible="true" version="6" changeset="13406299" timestamp="2012-10-07T23:36:07Z" user="Davlak" uid="217070" lat="41.8994226" lon="12.4969449"/>`. Column character isn't a field, is a tag, such like: `<tag k="bus" v="yes"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
  <tag k="internet_access" v="wlan"/>
  <tag k="internet_access:name" v="AtacWiFi"/>
  <tag k="internet_access:operator" v="RomaWireless"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Nazionale/Quattro Fontane"/>
  <tag k="operator" v="ATAC"/>
  ...`, right?

Comment: Thank you @aldo_tapia, but I didn't understand you. I was complaining that GDAL always launders the OSM key names when converting to shapefile format (colon from the OSM key's name is converted to an underscore in shapefile' field name). Then you said that: "I check field names in QGIS and are right". So I thought that when you did a conversion from .osm to .shp, the laundering was not performed. But when I opened your shape files from rome_osm_test.zip, it looks like you used just a couple of defined keys,and none of them contained colon.So I can not see if the laundering is performed or not

Comment: Tags are like description on `.kml` files, in a field you can have a lot of tags, even `.osm` files have a similar structure than `.kml`. If you want to extract tags use [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis), not GDAL to create new fields based on those tags. Are you trying to get something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgvtend9dmnhgum/lines.zip?dl=0)?

Comment: I downloaded your file but I still do not understand you. I am not familiar with .kml format so I can not comment on that.
What GDAL ogr2ogr.exe file does when converting from .osm to .shp is that it takes an .osm file geometry, and sorts it according to different geometry types (nodes, lines, closed lines...) and creates separate shapefiles according to these geometry types. It creates fields for each one of those geometry types. One can set the names of those fields to correspond to the names of keys from the .osm file. So not tags (key+value) but keys.

Comment: The rome.osm I attached above contains quite some nodes with colons in their key names. Can you convert it to a .shp file where filtered field names would be for example: ```addr:housenumber```, ```addr:postcode``` and ```addr:street```. This is all I want to know: if the field names in the resulting shapefiles still contain the colon. If they do, can you please comment the ```attribute_name_laundering=yes``` line your osmconf.ini file, and then try to convert them again? Are colons still laundered after this?

Comment: A field name can't hold colons. Solution: open your `.osm` file with any text editor and replace colons with underlines, save it and export to shapefile. `.osm` file is an XML, you can manage contents easily.

Comment: Thank you @aldo_tapia. GDAL's ogr2ogr.exe is doing that without me having to replace the colons manually. How does your last reply relate with the one you made initially: ```they can contain any combination of the letters A through Z, the digits 0 through 9, the colon (:) (in dBASE II field names only)```? How to know whether the resulting shapefile is a dBASE III or dBASE II?

Comment: Use [HexEd](https://hexed.it) to view raw bits and check [Xbase Data file](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/dbf.html#DBF_NOTE_1_TARGET) to translate bits. I tried it and result was DBF III version.

Answer (score 5):

According to the same Esri article that you cite:

> These limits are imposed so that ArcGIS is able to function with the
>   maximum amount of data types.

Consequently, even if you are not prevented from using the colon in a field name by whatever software you are using to create shapefiles, you will be unwise to use them with ArcGIS.